# In an empty environment, how are executables found?

Tags: shell, binary

For experimentation purposes I created a binary that prints the `$PATH`, and calls `which` as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *path = getenv("PATH");

    if (path)
        printf("got a path: %s\n", path);
    else
        printf("got no path\n");

    system("which which");
    return 0;
}
```

when I run it in an empty environment via

```
env -i ./printpath
```

I get the following printout:

```
got no path
/usr/bin/which
```

My question is: **why is the correct `which` binary called, even if there is no `$PATH`?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have used `system` function, so it will use another shell to run the command `which which`. From `man system`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       system()  executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
       command, and returns after the command has been completed.  During exe‐
       cution  of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT
       will be ignored.
```

If you change `which which` command to `echo $PATH`:

```
$ env -i ./a.out 
got no path
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

If you change your code to use `execve` instead of `system`, you will get expected output:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                             
#include <stdio.h>  

int main() {                                                                    
    char *path = getenv("PATH");                                                

    if (path)                                                                   
        printf("got a path: %s\n", path);                                       
    else                                                                        
        printf("got no path\n");                                                

    execve("echo $PATH");                                                       
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Compile and run it:

```
$ gcc test.c && env -i ./a.out 
got no path
```

Comment: i expected the subshell to inherit the empty path and therefore had no consequence. thank you for pointing out that missconception!

Comment: The subshell *does* inherit the empty path.  However, as a feature of bash (and presumably other shells too), if it is started with PATH unset, it sets it to a default value, which is what we see in the `echo $PATH` example.

Answer (score 3):

In an empty environment, executables are not found unless you specify the full path. Try it with `execvp`.

The `system` function invokes a shell — on Linux with Glibc, it invokes `/bin/sh` (so no `PATH` needed). Shells define a few variables of their own in addition to the ones coming from the environment. You can see what they define by running `env -i /path/to/shell -c set`, and which ones they export by running `env -i /path/to/shell -c export`. In particular, both dash and bash — the two shells that you're likely to find as `/bin/sh` on Linux — set (but do not export) `PATH` to a “sane” default if there isn't one in the environment. Different shells set different values or none at all.

```
$ env -i bash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ env -i dash -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ env -i mksh -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/bin:/bin
$ env -i ksh93 -c 'echo $PATH'

$ env -i zsh -c 'echo $PATH' 
/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/local/bin
$ env -i csh -c 'echo $PATH' 
PATH: Undefined variable.
$ env -i tcsh -c 'echo $PATH'
PATH: Undefined variable.
```

On my machine (and yours, apparently), `which` is itself a `/bin/sh` script. The shell invoked by `system` uses its own path variable to find the `which` program, but does not export it. The shell that runs the `which` script itself also defines the `PATH` variable for its internal use.